# How can I create a sequence that also repeats the last value when specified entries are present in another vector in R?

Tags: r, sequence

I'd like to create what's displayed under x2.

I'd like to start off at one and make the value in x2 increase one value each time. When TRUE is present in x1, this value should increase once and remain the same unless three or more TRUE's follow in which case it should increase a value of one during every other pair of TRUE's.

A TRUE in x1 will always be following by at least one more TRUE in the next row.

Example problem and desired results:

```
x1<-c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
x2<-c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11)
data.frame(x1, x2)

      x1 x2
1  FALSE  1
2  FALSE  2
3   TRUE  3
4   TRUE  3
5  FALSE  4
6   TRUE  5
7   TRUE  5
8  FALSE  6
9   TRUE  7
10  TRUE  7
11  TRUE  8
12  TRUE  8
13 FALSE  9
14  TRUE 10
15  TRUE 10
16 FALSE 11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cumsum(ave(as.logical(x1), x1, FUN = function(x){
    if(x[1] == TRUE) {
        rep(1:0, length.out = length(x))
    } else {
        rep(1, length(x))
    }
}))
#[1]  1  2  3  3  4  5  5  6  7  7  8  8  9 10 10 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have over-complicated this but here is a way :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(gr = data.table::rleid(x1)) %>%
  mutate(gr1 = !x1 |  (x1 & row_number() %% 2 == 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(out = cumsum(gr1)) %>%
  select(-gr, -gr1)


#    x1     x2   out
#   <lgl> <int> <int>
# 1 FALSE     1     1
# 2 FALSE     2     2
# 3 TRUE      3     3
# 4 TRUE      3     3
# 5 FALSE     4     4
# 6 TRUE      5     5
# 7 TRUE      5     5
# 8 FALSE     6     6
# 9 TRUE      7     7
#10 TRUE      7     7
#11 TRUE      8     8
#12 TRUE      8     8
#13 FALSE     9     9
#14 TRUE     10    10
#15 TRUE     10    10
#16 FALSE    11    11
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
df <- type.convert(df)
```